# Configuration Error 'Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection'

Tags: asp.net, iis, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I created a sample asp.net 4.0 application which includes a Facebook Connect button. I run the website on IIS.

The site is working fine. But the application gives me error whenever I deployed it in IIS.

After changing all the values, the root cause of the error is by changing the "idle time-out" in the application pool.

Here is what I did to reproduce this error:

1.Build the site and let it run through IIS.(In visual studio by changing in the website properties to run in custom webserver).

2.Change the idle timeout in the application pool (in advanced setting) to 1 or 2 min.

3.Run the website, login through the facebook. Then don't refresh it. After 1 or 2 min, you will get this error.

**ERROR:**

> Server Error in '/Facebooktestjan2011' Application.
>
> Configuration Error  Description: An
>   error occurred during the processing
>   of a configuration file required to
>   service this request. Please review
>   the specific error details below and
>   modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: An error
>   occurred creating the configuration
>   section handler for facebookSettings:
>   Could not load type
>   'Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> `Line 8:  <configuration>
>
>   Line 9:   <configSections>
>
>   Line 10:    <section name="facebookSettings"> type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection"/>
>
>   Line 11:   </configSections>
>
>   Line 12:   <connectionStrings>`
>
> Source File: C:\FacebooktestJan2011\web.config    Line: 10

**Page details:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"
         Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <fb:login-button  autologoutlink='true' 
                      onlogin="window.location.reload()"  
                      Title="Facebook Connect">
     </fb:login-button>
     <asp:label id="lblFBStatus" runat="server" ForeColor="black"/>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script>
        FB.init({ appId: 'appid', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function (response) {
            if (response.session) {
                // A user has logged in, and a new cookie has been saved
                //                location.href = "../TestFolder/Test.aspx";
            } else {
                // The user has logged out, and the cookie has been cleared
            }
        });
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Code Behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Dynamic;
using Facebook;

public partial class FacebookTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FacebookApp fbApp = new FacebookApp();

        if (fbApp.Session != null)
        {
            dynamic myinfo = fbApp.Get("me");
            String firstname = myinfo.first_name;
            String lastname = myinfo.last_name;
            lblFBStatus.Text = "you signed in as " + firstname + 
                               " " + lastname + " to use this credential ";

        }
        else
        {
            lblFBStatus.Text = "Please sign in with facebook";

        } 
    }
}
```

---

**Web.config file:**

```
<configuration>  
  <configSections>  
    <section name="facebookSettings" type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection"/>  
  </configSections>  
  <facebookSettings  
     appId="appid"  
     appSecret="appsecret"  
     cookieSupport="true" />  
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <httpHandlers>  
        <add verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd"    
             type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web" />
      </httpHandlers>  

  </system.web>  
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

    <handlers>
      <add name="facebookredirect.axd" verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd"                                   
          type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There are a number of funky things in your Web.config sample that make me wonder if they are transcription errors or the actual erroneous entries.  For example --facebookSettings and the space in cookieSuppor t

Comment: Actually i am not able to post the actual content of web.config file here...so i removed the opening marks and posted it here...if you want the actual file...i can send it to you....

Comment: Why can't you post it on here? It would be better if you could include the actual web.config file.

Comment: I am not able to post the web.config file...configuration section. <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="facebookSettings" type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection"/>
  </configSections>
  <facebookSettings
   appId="appid"
    appSecret="appsecret"
    cookieSupport="true" />

Comment: I am trying to use the version 4.2.1 of facebook-sdk, by using CSASPNETWEBSITE, but the login button is not showing in the login page. currently i am using 4.1.1 version. The error usually occurs whenever the idle timeout expires in IIS.

Comment: @suren - can you please learn about the code formatting features of the editor ( the {} symbol): http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

In Facebook C# SDK 4.2.1, I got around the error by making an instance of `FacebookSettings`, explicitly setting into it the app Id and secret key *(I kept them in the regular AppSettings section of config)* and passed this explicit settings instance to the `FacebookApp` constructor.

Example:

```
using Facebook;

var customSettings = new FacebookSettings();
customSettings.AppId = "PUT_APP_ID_HERE";
customSettings.AppSecret = "PUT_SECRET_HERE";

FacebookApp fbApp = new FacebookApp(customSettings);
// success for me
```

This error happened to me when I was running code from a C# unit test project without a web context present.
I didn't need to go to this trouble in the website code.