# Unable to authenticate on CSASPNETwebsite facebooksdk sample

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

The CSASPNETwebsite sample shown in the release 4.2.1 is not able to authenticate the user. I am not sure where i have to provide appsecret and appid other than providing the appid in the login page script. And also the login button is not showing in the login page, i think we have to add the tag in the site.master page

```
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is an extra unused sample.. there's no Facebook integration in it (I'm a developer and I typically handle the samples... I saw that one the other day and asked one of the other developers about). Use one of the other samples.

BTW, your appid/secret will go in the Web.Config.

DevTheo

Comment: Can you please provide any sample for doing it. coz i having error in getting this done in asp.net website(non mvc)...The error i am getting is explained here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716849/configuration-error-facebook-facebookconfigurationsection . Appreciated your help.

Comment: The CSASPNETFacebookApp sample is a C# WebForms example. The VBASPNETFacebookApp sample is a VB WebForms example. The CSMVCFacebookApp sample is a C# ASP.NET example. I'm guessing these are what you are looking for (there are a couple other web samples.. but these are the major ones).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good sample app for facebook auth 2.0 using facebook sdk from codeplex. It uses CSASPNETFacebookApp [Facebook Auth 2.0 with facebooksdk from codeplex](http://facebooksdk.blogspot.com/2011/03/facebookloginhelper.html)